# How to round each array element in an array column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Say I have a table `results` that contains a `score` column that is an array full of scores:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  scores numeric[]
);
```

I would like to update the table so that I round each score to 4 decimal places.

I have created a rounding function `round_numeric_array` that works for a single array value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_numeric_array (numeric[]) RETURNS numeric[]
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
   SELECT array_agg(round(unnest($1), 4))
$$;
```

But how do I apply it to every value in the table? I've been trying

```
UPDATE results SET scores = round_numeric_array(scores)
```

But I get a `set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set` error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the `unnest()` function in the FROM clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_numeric_array (numeric[]) 
RETURNS numeric[]
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS $$
   SELECT array_agg(round(elem, 4))
   FROM unnest($1) as arr(elem);
$$;
```

Note, that the function is immutable, read more in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html)